# Create and get when not exists specific records in DB in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I want to get relation with its default data. And i'm wondering how to implement it in a graceful way

This is the relationship

Store "hasMany" StoreProducts 
StoreProduct "belongsTo" Store

There's a hard coded array for StoreProduct as default data and
Store may already have non-default StoreProduct or a part of default StoreProduct in DB

and if default StoreProduct does not exist in DB, it has to be inserted into the DB then returned when getting it. 
 ex) $store->products

The below is the code.

```php
// Store.php

class Store 
{
    // …
    public function products()
    {
        return tap(
            $this->hasMany(StoreProduct::class, 'store_code', 'code'),
            function ($products) {
                StoreProduct::defaults()->each(function ($product) use ($products) {
                    if ( ! $products->get()->firstWhere('product_id', $product->product_id)) {
                        $products->save($product);
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    }
}
```

```php
// StoreProduct.php

class StoreProduct 
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'store_code',
        'price',
    ];

    public function store() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class, 'store_code', 'code');
    }
   
    public static function defaults()
    {
        return collect([
            new StoreProduct(['product_id' => 'car', 'price' => 1000]),
            new StoreProduct(['product_id' => 'desktop', 'price' => 300]),
        ]);
    }
}
```

```php
// routes/api.php

Route::get('stores/{store}/products', 'StoreProductController@index');
Route::get('stores/{store}/products/{product:product_id}', 'StoreProductController@show');
```

```php
// StoreProductController.php

class StoreProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request, Store $store)
    {
        return StoreProductResource::collection($store->products);
    }

    public function show(Store $store, StoreProduct $product)
    {
        return new StoreProductResource($product);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried eloquent firstOrCreate method? here it is: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models

Comment: Yup and in the case that Store already has StoreProduct, firstOrCreate doesn't fit for it

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Model Observer to handle such case, you can add a [dedicated observer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers) for your model with all actions or you can create a local observer like the following one, place it within your `Store.php` model:

```php
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        // Option 1, when you are retrieving a Store, check if it got the default products
        static::retrieved(function (Store $store) {
            // This line is for performance only, if you want to remove it then add () to
            // $store->products below, so it would be: $store->products()
            $store->loadMissing('products');
            StoreProduct::defaults()->each(function ($defaultProduct) use ($store) {
                if ( ! $store->products->where('product_id',$defaultProduct->product_id)->exists()) {
                    StoreProduct::create($defaultProduct);
                }
            });
        });

        // Option 2, after a store is saved, simply, create its default products
        //... take the code above and tweak it a bit, first change 'retrieved' to 'saved'
    }
```

Note: I really don't advise you to use 'product_id' as a string, or just rename it if you wish!

Cheers